# How secure is my BitLocker-encrypted disk after a fresh Win10 install?

Tags: windows-10, security, bitlocker

I've just installed a fresh Win 10 Pro on a new computer's NVMe drive, on a smaller partition C. After the installation I created another partition - D. To my suprise, both partitions are shown as "BitLocker Encrypted" even though I didn't set it up and have no keys generated.

How secure is this? My biggest concern here is if someone steals my computer and takes out the drive, will they be able to read it or do I need to "complete" the BitLocker set up to ensure this kind of protection?
[image]

Comment: What BitLocker protector are you using. Edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: Apparently, though BitLocker is operating, it's using your Windows login credentials (and possibly TPM) to access the drives. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bitlocker-windows-10-no-password-on-setup/27e322f9-6ce0-46f7-a074-6720d8f28814 "How secure," whether using existing login credentials or with a separate password,  is a matter of opinion, not addressed here.

Comment: I think the default answer for "how secure" to anything you didn't set up or don't understand yourself, has to be "assume it isn't" I would also say that windows is inherently insecure, so if you actually need data security...

Comment: The BitLocker Protector is whatever Win10 used by default.

Comment: @Val Bitlocker has multiple ways to unlock an encrypted volume. Some of them are very secure and incorporate a TPM, others not. So it depends on what is configured. These ways to unlock are called "protectors", this what Ramhound was asking for. Typically you can check this by manage-bde command, if your Windows Home edition I am not sure if the command is available.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Microsoft account to logon with and your device has supported hardware, Windows activates Bitlocker automatically and uploads a 48-digit numerical recovery password to your Microsoft cloud space. The encryption is transparent (TPM only) by default.
Secure? Sure, as long as you don't fear someone to get past your TPM. That however is possible, but only for people with some skill ("TPM sniffing"/Cold Boot attack").

If a thief removes the drive, it will not be accessible, since the only way to access it then is the aforementioned 48-digit-numerical-password.

For best security: add a preboot authentication PIN to Bitlocker (https://www.howtogeek.com/262720/how-to-enable-a-pre-boot-bitlocker-pin-on-windows/ ), then remove the recovery key from your MS account (if you don't trust their cloud security) and put that 48 digits into a safe place.

Comment: I don't use a Microsoft account as I'm paranoid about them spying on me. So I guess, my disk is still not protected now and will be only after I finish the BitLocker setup and apply PIN authentication?

Comment: Val, is it possible that someone else uses your machine and logs on with an MS account? Disk management would not claim that it is bitlocked if that wasn't the case. The only other possible reason for auto-bitlocking would be that your device is joined to a windows domain where this automation is enforced.